# Why it is safe to update some properties of a control from another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Why it is safe to update part of the properties of `System.Windows.Forms.Control` from another thread compared to other properties that are not safe and the programmer must use a `Delegate`?

For example, `ForeColor` compare to `Text`.

Could someone explain this from a design perspective?

Comment: Where is it documented that `ForeColor` is thread-safe?

Comment: Just because it doesnt throw an exception every time doesnt mean it is safe to do so.

Comment: Please be more specific. What properties do you claim to know with certainty may be accessed cross-thread safely?

Comment: when i try to update Text property InvalidOperationExeption is thrown and when i try to update forecolor or backcolor no exception is thrown and the property is updating. from what i know .net dont let make Cross-thread operation and raises an exception. isnt it points that forecolor (for example) is safe?

Comment: From MSDN: `An InvalidOperationException is thrown when you try to access a UI element from a thread other than the UI thread.` also the text of the exception: **Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.**  It doesnt say anything about some properties, it refers to accessing the control.

Comment: maybe using the term safe was not appropriate here. in simple terms what is the reason that text raises an exception and ForeColor not - to my understanding  forecolor is also accessed from thread it wasnt created on (sorry for my rusty English).

Comment: Probably the most constructive way to think about it is: if Microsoft could *reliably* tell that code is not thread-safe and throw an InvalidOperationException then why didn't they fix it and **make** it thread-safe?  Would have saved programmers a lot of time and grief.  They couldn't.  The check is a *heuristic*, it is about 97% accurate.  Which is a wholeheckofalot more than you usually get when trying to write thread-safe code.  Sure, you don't get the exception when you read the Text property or assign ForeColor.  The heuristic doesn't work on them.  Doesn't make them safe.

Comment: The errors are thrown only to notify you of an illegal cross-thread call. Performing such cross-thread calls is still possible if you set the control's `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` property to False, but it might (or will most likely) cause concurrency issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question as to why some property accesses raise an illegal cross-thread error and other do not, you can refer to the [source code for `System.Windows.Forms.Control`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,9884211b7ff61817).  It takes bit of digging through it, but it does appear as though some access is suggested as as being thread-safe such as getting the `Text` property but setting it is not.

In reality, the conventional wisdom to treat all control access as not thread safe is the best practice.

```
public virtual string Text {
    get {
        if (CacheTextInternal) {
            return(text == null) ? "" : text;
        }
        else {
            return WindowText;
        }
    }

    set {
        if (value == null) {
            value = "";
        }

        if (value == Text) {
            return;
        }

        if (CacheTextInternal) {
            text = value;
        }
        WindowText = value;
        OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);

        if( this.IsMnemonicsListenerAxSourced ){
            for( Control ctl = this; ctl != null; ctl = ctl.ParentInternal ) {
                ActiveXImpl activeXImpl = (ActiveXImpl)ctl.Properties.GetObject(PropActiveXImpl);
                if( activeXImpl != null ) {
                    activeXImpl.UpdateAccelTable();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Note the use of the internal WindowText property in the above code.

```
    /// <devdoc>
    ///     The current text of the Window; if the window has not yet been created, stores it in the control.
    ///     If the window has been created, stores the text in the underlying win32 control.
    ///     This property should be used whenever you want to get at the win32 control's text. For all other cases,
    ///     use the Text property - but note that this is overridable, and any of your code that uses it will use
    ///     the overridden version in controls that subclass your own.
    /// </devdoc>
    internal virtual string WindowText {
        get {

            if (!IsHandleCreated) {
                if (text == null) {
                    return "";
                }
                else {
                    return text;
                }
            }

            using (new MultithreadSafeCallScope()) {

                // it's okay to call GetWindowText cross-thread.
                //

                int textLen = SafeNativeMethods.GetWindowTextLength(new HandleRef(window, Handle));

                // Check to see if the system supports DBCS character
                // if so, double the length of the buffer.
                if (SystemInformation.DbcsEnabled) {
                    textLen = (textLen * 2) + 1;
                }
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(textLen + 1);
                UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(new HandleRef(window, Handle), sb, sb.Capacity);
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
        set {
            if (value == null) value = "";
            if (!WindowText.Equals(value)) {
                if (IsHandleCreated) {
                    UnsafeNativeMethods.SetWindowText(new HandleRef(window, Handle), value);
                }
                else {
                    if (value.Length == 0) {
                        text = null;
                    }
                    else {
                        text = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note the use of `MultithreadSafeCallScope` in the `get` code.  Also note the use of the `Handle` property that will throw a cross-thread error;  I believe the `Handle` property acts as the *gate-keeper* that checks for cross-thread access.

```
public IntPtr Handle {
    get {
        if (checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls &&
            !inCrossThreadSafeCall &&
            InvokeRequired) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.IllegalCrossThreadCall,
                                                             Name));
        }

        if (!IsHandleCreated)
        {
            CreateHandle();
        }

        return HandleInternal;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer, exactly the answer i was hoping to get.